# Does Cayley Table that is symmetrical along the diagonal with identities really mean the group is Abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cayley-table

I am having this doubt because Cayley Table for integers under mod 4 seems to be Abelian but its Cayley Table doesn't seem to be symmetrical.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwHspSCXFNM&list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6&index=6

But I was watching this short lecture on Cayley Table where they say if the Cayley Table is symmetrical then the group must be Abelian.

Comment: First: the table of the integers modulo $4$ **is** symmetrical: the $(i,j)$ entry is the same as the $(j,i)$ entry. Second: Even if it weren't, they are saying "If X then Y" and you are asking about "If Y then X".

Comment: If the rows and columns are labeled in the same order (so the $i$th row corresponds to the same element as the $i$th column), then the group is abelian **if and only if** the table is symmetric. Because if $a$ is the $i$th element and $b$ is the $j$th element, then $ab=ba$ means that the $(i,j)$ entry is the same as the $(j,i)$ entry and conversely; that is, the table is symmetrical if and only if $ab=ba$ holds for all $a,b$ in the group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, I thought when she said symmetrical, I was assuming the diagonal must be all identities. I think that only tells us that the group elements are inverses of themselves. Thanks for the clarification!